# c# xamarin unable to expand the web view using xamarin cross platform project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

[Actual screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRz3A.png)
See the attached image here, I have 4 buttons in a gird when any of them are clicked they show me a webview, but for some reason I am unable to expand the web view so that it covers rest of the screen. As you can see in the picture , webview is in a single column and buttons are in 1 row. I would really appreciate help. Thanks.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace LocalDataAccess
    {
        public partial class RecipeSites : ContentPage
        {
            public RecipeSites()
            {
                this.Content = gridlayout();
            }

            public Grid gridlayout()
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White;

                Button allrecipes = new Button
                {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                };
                allrecipes.Clicked += new EventHandler(allrecipes_Click);
                allrecipes.Image = "alrecipe.png";

                Button delia = new Button
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,

                };
                delia.Clicked += new EventHandler(delia_Click);
                delia.Image = "delia.gif";

                Button bbc = new Button
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                };
                bbc.Clicked += new EventHandler(bbc_Click);
                bbc.Image = "bbc.jpg";

                Button food = new Button
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                };
                food.Clicked += new EventHandler(food_Click);
                food.Image = "food.jpg";

                var grid = new Grid();
                RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();

                gridRow1.Height = new GridLength(7, GridUnitType.Star);
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
                grid.Children.Add(allrecipes, 0, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(delia, 1, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(bbc, 2, 1);
                grid.Children.Add(food, 3, 1);
                return grid;
            }

            public void food_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Grid sl = gridlayout();

                WebView webView = new WebView
                {
                    Source = new UrlWebViewSource
                    {
                        Url = " http://www.food.com/",
                    },
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

                };
                var grid1 = new Grid()
                { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
               ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
               c2.Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star);
               grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);
                grid1.Children.Add(webView, 3,1 );
                this.Content = sl;
            }

            public void allrecipes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Grid sl = gridlayout();

                WebView webView = new WebView
                {
                    Source = new UrlWebViewSource
                    {
                        Url = "http://allrecipes.co.uk/",
                    },
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

                };

                sl.Children.Add(webView);
                this.Content = sl;
    }

    public void delia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Grid sl = gridlayout();

            WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = "http://www.deliaonline.com/recipes",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        sl.Children.Add(webView);
        this.Content = sl;
    }

    public void bbc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Grid sl = gridlayout();

            WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource
            {
                Url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        sl.Children.Add(webView);
        this.Content = sl;
    }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a span value if you want a control to go across multiple rows or columns

```
// add button to col 0 row 4
controlGrid.Children.Add (zeroButton, 0, 4);
// make the button span 2 columns
Grid.SetColumnSpan (zeroButton, 2);
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show the modified code?

Comment: You really need to refactor your code.  Every time you click a button your are recreating the entire layout.  You only need to create the layout once, and then on each button click you just tell the existing webview to load a different url

Comment: i am new to all this, i sort of get your point could you show me how can i refactor this code..thanks

Comment: all your button click events should need to do is set the url of the webview.  In order to do that a) create the webview in your gridLayout() method  b) declare the webview variable as a class level variable (not inside a specific method) so you can access it from each button click